# Does tensorflow image in docker use GPU?

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

I have question whether my docker uses GPU.

My desktop has GeForce 2060 super and Ryzen 5 3600.

I implemented CNN with tensorflow.
The each image has from 20 to 50 kB.

When I use only CPU, each epoch spend 23 seconds (around 95ms/step).
On the other hand, when I use tensorflor-gpu-jupyter image in docker,
each epoch spend 21 seconds (around 83ms/step).
My docker command is following.

```
docker run --gpus all --rm -p 8888:8888 -v $PWD/CNN:/tf/notebooks tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter
```

I heard that GPU accelerate it 5 to 10 times faster,
but for me didn't.

Does my docker use GPU?

FYR. I checked nvidia working with following command.

```
docker run --gpus all --rm nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi
```

Answer (score 2):

Official TensorFlow images for Docker are GPU enabled, if the host system is properly configured ([source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker?hl=en)). You should pull the images with the `-gpu` tag.

Easiest way to check: use [nvtop](https://github.com/Syllo/nvtop) or `nvidia-smi -l 10` to check for GPU usage in the host system.

Notice that for enabling GPU support, you should have installed the [NVIDIA Container Toolkit.](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/install-guide.html#docker)

Comment: With command ```nvidia-smi -l 10```, it showed "Memory-Usage 7884Mib/7981, GPU-Util 4%" during running python. Does the GPU working?

Comment: Hm... I couldn't tell. So much memory allocated is definitely a sign that something is going on, but the GPU usage is low. May be due to infrautilization or that you did the check in an idle cycle. I highly recommend installing nvtop and checking there, since it will show the processes that are using the GPU so you'll definitely tell whether it's working or not.

Comment: I try start nvtop and it showed `Impossible to initialize nvidia nvml : Driver/library version mismatch`. I think this cause gpu not to work well. I will reinstall nvidia and try that again.